Classification of principal $\mathrm{SO}(3)$-bundles on a 4-manifold via characteristic classes


I am interested in a reference with a detailed (as simple and topological as possible) proof of the following fact:


Theorem. A principal $\mathrm{SO}(3)$-bundle on a compact oriented 4-manifold are determined by its second Stiefel-Whitney class and first Pontryagin class.
This is Theorem E.8 (Appendix) in Uhlenbeck, Freed - Instantons and 4-Manifolds (1984, 2-ed 1991), but I have difficulty following this text. For example, in the arguments preceding the theorem:

Why is the universal covering of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ called the adjoint representation? UPD: I figured out the answer to this question: the covering $\mathrm{SU}(2) \to \mathrm{SO}(3)$ is exactly the adjoint action of the unit quaternions on the pure imaginary quaternions.

How are weights and characteristic classes related?


I tried to browse the reference A. Borel, F. Hirzebruch - Characteristic Classes and Homogeneous Spaces (1958) given there, but so far I have not been able to understand what it is about (another reminder to never reference without citing a specific place).
I suspect that even if I can understand the answers to these questions, I will quickly get stuck again.


Any recommendations for more modern texts covering these topics?


This theorem was discussed on MO, but there were no more modern references mentioned.

What do you mean, precisely, by 'modern reference'?

@mme I meant just expositions written later, which might be more complete/readable. I should have written the word "more" to be clearer, yes. Fixed.

Another possible reference, but also from around the time of Borel-Hirzebruch is Dold and Whitney "Classification of oriented sphere bundles over a 4-complex", Ann. Math. 69, 1959. The proof is obstruction-theoretic (and for more general complexes, not just manifolds). Maybe a bit more focused on the concrete SO(3)-bundle classification problem than Borel-Hirzebruch. Dold and Whitney reference Pontryagin 1945 for an earlier classification result for SO(3)-bundles.
